# How to clone method in a dynamic add row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a method that will trigger once the user type anything in the textbox (onChange) but this code is only implemented when another method is called.

The problem is it can only work at one row and it will not work anymore on the following add rows.

add row through jquery

```
 $('#data').append('<tr><td> <input type="checkbox" name="chk" /> </td><td><input type="hidden" name = "itemCode"/><input type="text" id= "itemName[]" value="' + data[0].itemName + '"/> </td><td><input type="text" id="unitPrice[]" name = "unitPrice" value="' + data[0].unitPrice + '"/></td><td><input type="number"  id="volumeQty[]"  onChange="SolveTQP();" name="volumeQty" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"/><td><input type="text" name = "Total Quantity Price" id="TQP[]"  /></td><td><input type="hidden" name = "receivingStatus" value="pending" /><input type="hidden" name = "reconcileStatus" value="pending" /><input type="text" name = "note"/></td>' + '</tr>');
```

method that is trigger onChange

```
 function SolveTQP() {
      $("#data").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var unitPrice = parseInt($this.find('[id="unitPrice\\[\\]"]').val());
                var volumeQty = parseInt($this.find('[id="volumeQty\\[\\]"]').val());
                var STotal = unitPrice * volumeQty;
                $this.find('[id="TQP\\[\\]"]').val(STotal);
            });
            return false;
    SolveTotal(STotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your giving your dynamically added elements duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. And getting the `.val()` of an element by referring to its `id` attribute will only ever return the value of the first element with that `id`.

Instead use class names and relative selectors. Append the html as

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name = "itemCode"/>
        <input type="text" class="itemName" value="' + data[0].itemName + '"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="unitPrice" name="unitPrice" value="' + data[0].unitPrice + '"/></td>

    you appear to be missing a closing </td> in the next line
    <td><input type="number"  class="volumeQty" name="volumeQty" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"/>
    <td><input type="text" name="Total Quantity Price" class="TQP" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="receivingStatus" value="pending" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reconcileStatus" value="pending" />
        <input type="text" name="note"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting your markup with behavior

```
$('#data').on('change', '.volumeQty', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var volumeQty = Number($(this).val());
    var unitPrice = Number(row.find('.unitPrice').val());
    row.find('.TQP').val(volumeQty  * unitPrice);
});
```

Note there seems no need to the total of every other row (the quantity did not change so its just pointless extra overhead. However if your wanting a grand total of each row in the element with `id="data"`, then add the following to the script

```
$('#data').on('change', '.volumeQty', function() {
    ....
    var total = 0;
    $.each($('#data tr'), function(index, item) {
      total += Number($(this).find('.TQP').val());
    });
    // set the total to some element?
});
```

Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Lc1zk3/1/)

Comment: THANK YOU :D, this helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

When you repeat the rows, and then try to fetch the elements by `id`, it doesn't work because you have multiple elements with same `id`. One alternative here without changing a lot of your existing code is to use a class on the row and use that class to iterate through your elements like this:

```
function SolveTQP() {
      $(".trclass").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var unitPrice = parseInt($this.find('[id="unitPrice\\[\\]"]').val());
                var volumeQty = parseInt($this.find('[id="volumeQty\\[\\]"]').val());
                var STotal = unitPrice * volumeQty;
                $this.find('[id="TQP\\[\\]"]').val(STotal);
            });
            return false;
    SolveTotal(STotal);
}

var data = [
    {itemName:"iphone", unitPrice:600},
    {itemName:"android", unitPrice:300}
    ];

$("#btn").on('click', function(){
      $('#data').append('<tr class="trclass"><td> <input type="checkbox" name="chk" /> </td><td><input type="hidden" name = "itemCode"/><input type="text" id= "itemName[]" value="' + data[0].itemName + '"/> </td><td><input type="text" id="unitPrice[]" name = "unitPrice" value="' + data[0].unitPrice + '"/></td><td><input type="number"  id="volumeQty[]"  onChange="SolveTQP();" name="volumeQty" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"/><td><input type="text" name = "Total Quantity Price" id="TQP[]"  /></td><td><input type="hidden" name = "receivingStatus" value="pending" /><input type="hidden" name = "reconcileStatus" value="pending" /><input type="text" name = "note"/></td>' + '</tr>');
});
```

```html
<table id="data">
</table>
<button id="btn">Add Row</button>
```

Here, the `.trclass` added to your row is used to iterate through the rows that are dynamically inserted. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t9xf0yj/).

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, a document should not contain more than one element with an `id`. In other words, `id` should be unique. You should be using `name`, `class` etc
- Your html string contains opening tags without closing tags
- Common standard is to capitalize first letter only for *constructor* functions. Better use `solveTQP`, `solveTotal` etc to avoid confusion
- You should pass the reference to element in the event handler like
     `<input type="number" name="volumeQty"class="volumeQty" onChange="solveTQP(this);"/>`
  ideally you should be using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) rather than inline event handlers

Once you fix all these, your code should be something like below assuming you're using `class` instead of `id` and you are calculating `total` based on the current row:

```
function solveTQP(elm) {
  var $this = $(elm);
  var $currentRow = $this.closest('tr');
  var unitPrice = parseInt($currentRow.find('.unitPrice').val(),10);
  var volumeQty = parseInt($this.val(),10);
  var sTotal = unitPrice * volumeQty;
  $currentRow.find('.totalQuantityPrice').val(sTotal);
  solveTotal(sTotal);
}
```